# Why doesn't an HTML anchor tag wrap a scalable SVG <object>?

Tags: object, svg, viewbox

I have created a scalable SVG object, using the `preserveAspectRatio` and `viewBox` attributes in the SVG file itself:

```
<svg
  …
  width="800"
  height="800"
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
  viewBox="0 0 800 800"
  …
```

In the HTML, I reference the SVG file using the `<object>` tag and wrap it an `<a>` tag (I want to do this so that I can style it later):

```
<a>
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="smiley.svg">
  </object>
</a>
```

I style the `<object>` tag with some CSS to make it 50% wide, and no wider than 100%:

```
object {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

The problem is that the anchor tag doesn't wrap all around the object!

[image: Anchor tag not wrapping scalable SVG object]

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element: _“Content model: Transparent, but there must be no [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant.”_

Comment: Eek, I can see the words but they don't make sense! Why, in simple english, would an `<object>` behave differently to a `<img>`?

Comment: Because an object can contain _interactive content_ (even SVG can be can interactive content itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @CBroe has it: SVG *can* be interactive content, therefore it shouldn't be wrapped by anchor element:

> [w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element](http://w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element): “Content model: Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.”

Answer (score 2):

Adding `display: block` to anchor seems to fix it for me.

Comment: If I style the anchor tag as `display: block`, it stretches the anchor tag to full width of the page, not 50% (ie around the object) :(

Comment: So make it floating or inline-block

Comment: I tried `float: left` and `display: inline-block` and they had the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found a fully working solution at [teamtreehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-you-make-a-svg-clickable).

It's a combination of `inline-block` and pseudo-elements.

Thomas Quayle [made a pen](http://codepen.io/thomasquayle/pen/KwxwoO) of the example solution (replicated below).

```css
a.svg {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25%;
}
a.svg:after {
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
}
object {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>SVG Link Demo</h1>
<blockquote>Replicated from <a href="http://codepen.io/thomasquayle/pen/KwxwoO">Thomas Quayle's codepen</a> example</blockquote>

<a href="http://google.com" class="svg">
  <object data="http://openclipart.org/people/cjcreativedesign/PuppyLongEars.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="mailicon">
  </object>
</a>
<a href="http://google.com" class="svg">
  <object data="http://openclipart.org/people/cjcreativedesign/PuppyLongEars.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="mailicon">
  </object>
</a>

<p>How cool is that?</p>
```